# How would I have a Discord bot (made in Python) go to a website and fetch a number from the website?

Tags: discord, discord.py

So I want to create a bot that will go to a website and fetch a number from the website. So let us say we have a website like this
[A basic website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UFjmK.png)

I want my bot to find that the value of that number is 5, then post a message saying something like "the number is 5!" Thanks so much, everyone!

Comment: You are looking for the `requests` module. Basically you need to do a GET request on the API endpoint and parse the response body in your bot.

Comment: For parsing you can use something like [Beautiful Soup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/).

Answer (score 0):

You should use `aiohttp` which is already included with discord.py. `requests` would result in [blocking](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#what-does-blocking-mean)

Here is a simple command to get the data, either as JSON or text.

```py
@bot.command()
async def get_info(ctx, *, link):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get(link) as r:
            if r.status == 200:
                info = await r.json()
                #or if it is text
                info = await r.text()
                
    await ctx.send(info)
```

Simple use case

- Json:
  `get_info https://uselessfacts.jsph.pl/random.txt`
- Text:
  `get_info https://uselessfacts.jsph.pl/random.json`